# Converting string to int from array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, int

I am trying to print out the exact location of an array element but am coming out short

```
string[] ocean = { "Beebo", "Jeff","Arthur", "Nemo", "Dory" };

foreach(string fish in ocean)
{
    if (fish == "Nemo")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We found Nemo on position {0}!",int.Parse(fish));
        return;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
```

I need the {0} token to be replaced with the array index of that element in this case with 3 but i am failing at the int.Parse(fish) which obviously isn't working

Comment: You could use `Array.IndexOf` to get the index of the fish name.  Otherwise either use a `for` loop where you control the index or add a variable that you increment in the `foreach` to keep track of the index.

Comment: I haven't thought of multiple occurences, i only need the one occurence printed

Comment: All positions: `string searchString = "Nemo"; int[] position = Enumerable.Range(0, ocean.Length).Where(idx => ocean[idx].Equals(searchString)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to get this working is by switching to a `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < ocean.Length; i++)
{
    if (ocean[i] == "Nemo")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We found Nemo on position {0}!", i);
        return;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
```

Alternatively you can keep track of the index in a `foreach`

```
int index = 0;
foreach(string fish in ocean)
{
    if (fish == "Nemo")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We found Nemo on position {0}!", index);
        return;
    }

    index++;
}
Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
```

Or you can avoid the loop altogether and use `Array.IndexOf`.  It will return -1 if the value is not found.

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(ocean, "Nemo");
if(index >= 0)
    Console.WriteLine("We found Nemo on position {0}!", index);
else
    Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
```

And here's a Linq solution

```
var match = ocean.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "Nemo");
if(match != null)
    Console.WriteLine("We found Nemo on position {0}!", match.Index);
else
    Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this was already known to me. I had my heart on a foreach this time

Comment: @Ale I've added a `foreach` solution and one that uses `Array.IndexOf`.  I also tend to prefer `foreach` loops, but when I also need the index I almost always end up going back to the `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing the probable solution in LINQ maybe and I hope it will be helpful. The error is due to the fact that indices in arrays start on zero it shows 3

```
   string[] ocean = { "Beebo", "Jeff","Arthur", "Nemo", "Dory" };

   ocean.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i }).ForEach(element =>
   {
       if (element.Value == "Nemo")
       {
           Console.WriteLine("We found Nemo on position {0}!",element.Index);
       }
   });
```

[How to use it in compiler](https://rextester.com/ZNAL14754)

Comment: A better Linq solution would be to use `Where(x => x.Value == "Nemo").FirstOrDefault()` and then you don't need to create a needless list with `ToList` just to use `ForEach`

Comment: good alternative, but it iterates twices through all elements, that's why it's not so efficient. And you can remove the ToList(), this isn't good for anything here.

Comment: @Holger The `ToList` is required to do the `ForEach`, but IMHO that's a horrible practice.

Comment: @juharr. Right, and your ideas misses the index. So if one wants to use LINQ, the answer is correct. Just to choose LINQ is not effective here.

Comment: Another issue with this solution is that it doesn't handle the case when no match is found.

Comment: @Holger I meant to replace the `ToList` and `ForEach` with the `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` so you'd still have the `Select` that captures the index.

Comment: @juharr Or just `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "Nemo")`. In any case, this is one of those cases which LINQ is unnecessary, and vanilla code is preferable.

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes, very true.

Comment: @juharr no, the select counts the index of the current IEnumerable. After the Where, the orginal index is lost. Unless you store it as an anonymous type, as in this answer.

Comment: @Holger Yes that's what I meant, that it would use the same `Select` before the `Where` that this answer uses that captures the original index in an anonymous class.